# Move Entity Framework entities configurations to separate class per Db

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use code-first approach and have used SQL Server as database. All the entities are configured like below:

```
public interface IBaseEntityTypeConfiguration<T>
{
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder);
}

// My entity
public class Student : IBaseEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
    {
         // Configure entity
    }
}
```

In the `ApplicationDbContext` all the classes which are inherited from `IBaseEntityTypeConfiguration` are added to the `modelBuilder.Configurations`.

But I came up with a new requirement. We should switch from SQL Server to PostgreSql!

I don't want to change the `Map()` method in all entities, but I want to add some kind of provider which says to `modelBuilder` that use configurations for SQL Server configurations or PostgreSql configs.

Something like below:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        // var entities = new MsSqlEntityConfiguration().GetAllTypes();
        var entities = new PostgreEntityConfiguration().GetAllTypes();

        foreach(entity in entities)
            modelBuilder.Configuration.Add(entity);    // As an example
    }
}
```

Is there any solution that exists as described?

Comment: There is a mdx mapping file that links the database tables with the c# classes.  The mapping file has to be compatible with the two databases.

Comment: No, there are differences. As an example when I want to configure JSONs or DateTimeOffsets.

Comment: If the mdx mapping file is the same you  do not need to do anything different.  The code should work as is.  Why do you need a different model?

Comment: @jdweng EF Core does not use mdx (whatever it is) or any *x files for mapping. Everything is via code. Please do not put misleading comments/suggestions on area you are not familiar with.